# Read frequency data from audio web API

Tags: javascript

I want to continue reading frequency data from audio stream with volume 0(muted).

I already tried using `analyser.getByteFrequencyData(fbc_array)` but the values are 0 when the audio is muted.

This is my code:

```
  var audio = new Audio();
  var url = 'http://sc15.shoutcaststreaming.us:8140/stream/;';
  audio.src = url;

  var context = new AudioContext();
  var analyser = context.createAnalyser();
  var source = context.createMediaElementSource(audio);
  source.connect(analyser);
  analyser.connect(context.destination);
  var fbc_array = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
  analyser.getByteFrequencyData(fbc_array);
```

Is it possible to still reading frequency data from audio with volume 0 or muted?

Comment: Not as far as I know, but you can add a [GainNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GainNode) between the analyser and the destination and use that to mute the output rather than muting / unmuting the source.